# jQuery UI tabs with Ajax-based content: how to avoid first panel loaded by AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

Suppose to use *jQuery UI tabs* and to load tabs content by means of an AJAX call, e.g.:

```
<div id="tabbed-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="url1">LINK1</a></li>
        <li><a href="url2">LINK2</a></li>
        <li><a href="url3">LINK3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with the following Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabbed-menu").tabs();
});
```

Now, on **document.ready** the tabbed menu is created and the *content* of the first tab is loaded by a **server request**.

Suppose I want to replace this additional unnecessary server request. For instance, I can load the page with the whole content of the first tab.

How con I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an id selector instead of an URL in the `href` attribute of the first tab. For instance:

```
<div id="tabbed-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#content1">LINK1</a></li>
        <li><a href="url2">LINK2</a></li>
        <li><a href="url3">LINK3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content1">
        Content of first tab.
    </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, if you want to let the first tab to be reloaded in a second time, you can:
1) add the url of the new content to the anchor, e.g.:

```
<a href="#content1" data-url="url1">LINK1</a>
```

2) Bind the tabbselect event to intercept the static content loading to replace it with a content reload, e.g.:

```
$("#private-area-menu").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
      if(ui.index==0){
          $('#tab-content').html(''); // required to clear the previous static data
          $('#tab-content').load($(ui.tab).attr('data-url')); // refresh data              
      }
});
```

Comment: Ok, this come from the tutorial. However, if for instance I move to Link2 and then I come back to Link1, the content of Link1 is not reloaded. Isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, it won't be reloaded. That said, AJAX tabs are only loaded once IIRC, so the dynamic tabs would not be reloaded either. *Edit: scratch the last sentence, that depends on the caching policy.*

Comment: Oh! Even If i set the cache to false?

Comment: Yup, I remembered badly, it depends on the cache settings.

Comment: Uh, ok! I guess I can force the reload of the first tab by hacking in such a way the "tabbselect" event? What do you argue?

Comment: I tried to put the URL back in the `href` attribute after the widget is created, but that doesn't work, even when calling the `refresh` method. I'll try a full destroy/create cycle.

Comment: Nope, even calling the internal `_tabify()` method doesn't work, as it leaves the original content `<div>` around. I'm not sure switching a tab from static to dynamic is actually possible...

Comment: I found a solution to the reload. Can I edit yours or should I post a new one?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overlap the callback function on tab load like:

```
$('#example').tabs({
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
                $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
});
```

or on the tab select like:

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var isValid = ... // form validation returning true or false
        return isValid;
    }
});
```

This snippets was taken from http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Tabs which I recommend you to read.